# Missing certificates after upgrading offlineimap

Tags: email, security, homebrew, certificate

I upgraded offlineimap via Homebrew and it is now now 8.0.0 with Python 3.10. Now I am missing the certificates:

```
 ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'imap.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com' for repository 'RepositoryAtletismoEmocional'. OpenSSL responded:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)
```

I searched for `Install Certificate.command` on the hard drive with no results. I also tried using package `certifi` with these commands in  `~/.bash_profile`:

```
CERT_PATH=$(python3 -m certifi)
export SSL_CERT_FILE=${CERT_PATH}
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=${CERT_PATH}
```

How can I install certificates to run `offlineimap`?

### Update

Upgrading the `brew` packages for other software, I see this line:

```
Installing dependencies for python@3.9: ca-certificates, sqlite, xz and libffi
```

I searched online about this and found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yelled3/a5eaf3ca90011aaf7e7901c55680ff06):

```
# Based on: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Mac/BuildScript/resources/install_certificates.command

# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.org/project/certifi/
import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys
STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )
def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])
    import certifi
    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But `offlineimap` still throws the same error:

```
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: Unknown SSL protocol connecting to host 'imap.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com' for repository 'RepositoryAtletismoEmocional'. OpenSSL responded:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)
```

### second update

I checked the `offlineimaprc` file and it uses:

```
ssl=true
sslcacertfile = /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

and that file is two years old. So maybe I just need to re-generate that certificate or point `offlineimap` to the macOS native certificate?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are having is a broken certificate chain. I am assuming that you have tried the tool with two different servers so we can rule out a coincidental breakage at the server end.

Handling certificates with Homebrew is not ideal. Your script might not be doing it well either. I'd try `pip3 install --upgrade certifi`

You might also check that your Python 3 script is finding the Python binary you think it's finding. Do a `which python3` and then try calling that Python 3 and passing it the script - e.g. something like `/usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/offlineimap` Also have a look at the top of `offlineimap` to check the shebang at line 1.

Finally the `offlineimap` web site says it supports being installed with pip so you could uninstall the Homebrew version and install it with `pip3 install --user offlineimap` (This will currently install version 7.3.4)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I removed the `brew` version and installed `certifi` and `offlineimap` with `python3 -m pip install <name>`. The shebang line of `offlineimap` points to `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9` (not symlinked) while `python3` points to `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9` (not symlinked). When I run `offlineimap` or `/usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/offlineimap`, I get the same message of a missing local issuer certificate, even after I run the `certifi` Python script.

Comment: I have not tried the tool with two different servers, no. Do you mean the Python script using `certifi`?

Comment: I added an update with the `offlineimap` configuration that points to the certificate, which was 2 years old. Maybe that would solve the issue?

Comment: That is some good debug work. I would try pointing the config at a different cert. I would also try turning SSL off just to confirm everything else is working.

Comment: Running without `ssl = true` throws: `ERROR: No CA certificates and no server fingerprints configured`. On trying other certificates, I could try the system ones but they seem accessible only through Keychain Access and not through a filepath. The `certifi` package installed one, but `offlineimap` fails with that certificate. I checked that it exists with `ls -laht /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`, which returns `-rwxrwxr-x  1 mmorin  admin   279K 28 Jul 13:00 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`. How can I try another certificate?